# Is it possible to retrieve a certain value from a website using jQuery web scraping?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to read a value from a website using web scrapping

The Site I am trying to read is

https://nseguide.com/stock.php?TATASTEEL

I am trying to read Support 1    value from here which is 106.9

`

I am getting the error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
> //*[@id="left-col"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/b

This is what i tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$.get('https://nseguide.com/stock.php?TATASTEEL', function(html) {

  alert($(html).find('//*[@id="left-col"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[4]').text());

});

});
```

I copied the xpath value using chrome inspect , pls let me know how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yon are not using jquery syntax to go to the element, try this:

```
$.get("https://nseguide.com/stock.php?TATASTEEL", function (html) {
     alert($(html).find(".stocks.box table tr:eq(5) td:eq(3)").text());
});
```